# Unit tests of a C# App crashes when the execution reaches C++ layer

Tags: c#, c++, windows-store-apps

We have a Windows Store App structured something like, MainApp(C#, Windows Store) --> ServiceLayer(C# Class Library) --> MainCode(C++, Windows Runtime Component).

There is no problem while running application in debug mode. But when I try to run a unit test project which refers MainApp, it crashes when it reaches C++ layer. And it is intermittent too. Sometimes with AccessViolation, other times with ArgumentException or just no exception at all.

Interestingly, that unit test works when I directly call ServiceLayer instead of going through MainApp.

What am I missing?

Comment: C++: AccessViolation: check your pointer usage. This is a very common problem if you have code in C/C++.

Comment: @linquize I checked. It seems to be all OK. If pointer usage was wrong, then it should have failed when I called through ServiceLayer instead of MainApp :( . Also it passes when application is running.